# Quality of Android Notification Icon

Tags: android, notifications

I have been trying to set the quality of my notification Icon in my application however it does not seem to be fixing. I have tried to import a larger image into my project so that the quality could be higher but that does not work. I have tried setting the notification's big icon to my image but that still does not work. How do I increase the quality of my notification icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Iconography guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification) gives information on the appropriate file size and styling of notification icons. In summary:

- Make assets 24dp x 24dp
- Draw inside a 22dp x 22dp square
- Use a flat and simple style
- Use white only

If you size your assets based on these recommendations, you should see the highest possible notification icon quality. If you use a large image (like your launcher image), Android will scale down the asset to 24dp x 24dp - scaling of this magnitude usually results in significant loss of quality.